# CollectionView.Footer hide/remove at runtime Xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to hide or remove the footer at runtime?

I have a footer with a view inside it in xaml,however I would like to add and remove the footer at runtime in the codebehind.How can I do that?

```
 <CollectionView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">    
    <CollectionView.EmptyView >
       <views1:MyEmptyView IsVisible ="{Binding IsEmptyViewVisible}" />
    </CollectionView.EmptyView>        

    <CollectionView.Footer >
        <MyFooterView IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}" />
    </CollectionView.Footer>
 </CollectionView>
```

Comment: Since you had bound the `IsVisible` in code behind , you just need to set it as `false` in runtime to hide the FooterView .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT thanks for your reply. despite visible=false it still takes the space allocated and is cutting something from my empty view. I would like to add/remove at runtime

Comment: Binding the height of `MyFooterView` and set it to zero .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT It does not help, space is still there.